# JSON - Get Chrome Tab Title

Tags: html, json, google-chrome

My Chrome extension loads a local .html file.

(inside the manifest.json file)

```
"default_popup": "popup.html",
```

Inside that html file, a frame is created to www.website.com, therefore being able to view www.website.com in the little popup my extension creates (using popup.js).

```
<iframe src="http://www.website.com" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0">
```

I would like for my Chrome Extension to change "www.website.com" to add onto the end of it the title of the current tab the Chrome user is viewing, minus any spaces and reducing the length to a maximum of 30 characters.

Example:
Bob has Chrome open to www.pbs.org, which has the title "PBS Public Broadcasting Service".  He clicks my Chrome extension and it drops down, showing him www.website.com/PBSPublicBroadcastingService in the dropdown window.  Bob is pleased.

Here is a screenshot of what the popup looks like:
http://julianapena.com/wp-content/uploads/HowtobuildaChromeextensionPart3Loadingan_13EA3/image_thumb.png

Answer (score 0):

According to the https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs

You can
Add "permissions": [
    "tabs"
], in your manifest file, in helper.js file add

```
function getCurrentTab(callback) {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tab) {
    tab = tab[0];
    return callback(tab);
  });
}
```

, and add in your popup.js

```
function Init() {
  getCurrentTab(function(tab) {
    ShowIframe(tab.title);
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', Init);
```

Also you can create chromeUI.js where you can define ShowIframe function.

Comment: I added the first bit of code you provided into my manifest.json file, but it returns an error.  Here is the code I have:

Comment: "permissions": [
    "Tabs",
    function getCurrentTab(callback) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tab) {
    tab = tab[0];
    return callback(tab);

Comment: "permissions": [
          "tabs"
        ]  in the manifest file, please look https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs, and then you can create helper.js file in your extension or define function getCurrentTab in popup js.

Comment: I am a complete noob to this stuff, and those tutorials explain specifics but forget the background.  I don't know where any of this goes.  I don't want to learn the full scale of JSON or anything like that.  I merely need to know how to do what I am asking for.  I am not going to further any education after I find the code I need.  I don't know what "helper.js" is or does.  I found some examples online and put them to work, but lack the know-how for a small problem that no one seems to be able to provide the answer to.  Forgive me if I am being short, but the link you provided doesn't help.

Comment: It gives me "types" and "properties", which I have no idea where they go.